# Why does CTRL-click on JavaScript Math function in VSCode show internal TypeScript code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, v8

I wanted to investigate the internals of the Math object in JavaScript as running in Node. I assumed I would get information on what C++ methods the V8 engine called, etc. but I get information showing TypeScript interfaces for the Math object.

Can anyone explain why TypeScript interfaces are being shown when one displays information on V8's implementation of JavaScript's Math object?

[image]

Comment: Because that's the only information available about the *TypeScript* function.

Comment: Why do you assume that your TS code is even executed by V8 and not some other JS engine?

Answer (score 1):

The underlying detailed engine implementation of functions

- Wouldn't make sense to the vast majority of script-writers
- are not standardized - there are different environments, VSCode wouldn't assume that the file being examined would always be running in V8

In comparison, the TypeScript documentation for these sorts of built-in functions *is* standardized, and is relatively simple to understand, even for those who may not have seen it before.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @CertainPerformance said:

- How engines implement built-in functions is completely up to them: it could be a JavaScript implementation (in which case you could certainly argue that it could be instructive for IDEs like VSCode to show the source), it could be C++ (or whichever language the engine is written in), it could be hand-written assembly; in case of current versions of V8, `Math.min` is implemented using V8's own DSL ("domain specific language") called "Torque", which despite looking a bit like TypeScript is a totally different beast under the hood (in short: it gets compiled to C++ source, which in turn is compiled to an executable that produces assembly code which is then embedded into the V8 binary).
- Compiled (C/C++/Rust/...) binaries in general (in Release builds) don't include information about which functions they consist of (much less those functions' source code), so there's no way for IDEs to get at that information even if they wanted to. (This is why "Debug" builds are a thing.)
- If you still want to study V8's implementation, you can find many of the `Math` builtins [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/main/src/builtins/math.tq).

So, showing the TypeScript definitions of the signatures of the `Math` builtins is pretty much the best that a JavaScript IDE can do.